# Is the composition of two injective functions injective?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Consider $f:A \to B$ and $g: B \to C$. If I know that both $f$ and $g$ are injective, then can I state that $$g  \circ f:A \to C$$ is injective?

Comment: Think it through. What is the criterion for whether or not $g \circ f$ is injective? How would you go about determining whether this holds or not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes,
$$f(a) = f(b) \iff a =b,$$
$$g(a) = g(b) \iff a =b,$$
so

$$g(f(a)) = g(f(b)) \implies f(a) = f(b) \implies a = b. $$

Answer (score 4):

Using "[injective iff has a left inverse](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Injection_iff_Left_Inverse)":

$f$ injective $\implies$ $\exists\tilde f:\ \tilde f\circ f = I_A$.

$g$ injective $\implies$ $\exists\tilde g:\ \tilde g\circ g = I_B$.

Now, the composition has left inverse, namely $\tilde f\circ \tilde g$:
$$(\tilde f\circ\tilde g)\circ(g\circ f) = \tilde f\circ\tilde g\circ g\circ f = \tilde f\circ I_B\circ f = \tilde f\circ f = I_A.$$

Comment: This is actually a better solution than the other one because it doesn't use elements at all. +1